# Should I use an article for the part "aesthetics of mind and body" in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions, articles

Should I use an article in the part "**aesthetics of mind and body**" in this sentence? If yes, then what article should I use?

> I am into meditations, philosophy, psychology, aesthetics of mind and body.

I am into aesthetics of my mind and body so it's specific and I should use an article "The" but in the sentence above it's not clear if I am talking about my or all minds and bodies so should I use an article "A"?

Comment: You could omit the article, use **the**, or **an**. It would depend on what you wanted to say.  We would normally use **meditation** in the singular, referring to the act generally, in the context you have presented.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo thank you for the information about meditation. So the article usage doesn't matter in the part "aesthetics of mind and body"?. If so, then I would use "The" because it sounds better to me. If I am going to use "The" article, should I use it only with "Mind" or with both "Mind" and "Body"? _Aesthetics of the mind and body_ or _Aesthetics of the mind and the body_?

Comment: I didn't say that it didn't matter. I said that your choice would depend on what you wanted to say. ***the** aesthetics* implies that you think that you and your reader agree on what that term refers to; ***an** aesthetics* implies that there are multiple aesthetics, and yours may be idiosyncratic;  omitting the article refers to aesthetics as a general area or approach with fuzzy boundaries.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I somehow totally missed the "It would depend on what you wanted to say.". Well explained. Thank you very much!